# sql server 2005 delphi 2010 dbexpress connection

Tags: sql-server-2005, delphi, delphi-2010, dbexpress

Trying to connect to sql server 2005 with delphi 2010 gives me the following error after configuring the data explorer:
**'Borland.data.TDBXError: DBX Error: Driver could not be properly initialized. Client library may be missing, not installed properly, or wrong version'**

I know there is a work around by installing the sql server 2008 management studio. But this is not a good solution if all pc's need to have this prerequirement.

Anybody know a better solution/fix.

Delphi 6 does not have this problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to install the SQL Server 2005 Client.
You can check the database deploy information in the Readme file in the Delphi install path.

**Installing SQL Server Native Client**
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131321.aspx

or you can download the feature pack
http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=50B97994-8453-4998-8226-FA42EC403D17&displaylang=en

I wrote this article about DBX + MSSQL in portuguese, you can use google to translate to your native language:
http://www.cesarromero.com.br/2010/configurando-dbx-para-acessar-o-ms-sql-server-2000-e-2005-no-delphi-2010/

Comment: Thanks, your article helped me.